# Is it the correct way to run multiple tags in Cucumber Serenity framework?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd

There are two tags that I want to run (preferably in sequence i.e. one after the other), Is the way right way to run?

```
mvn clean test -Pqa verify -Dthread.count=4 -Dcucumber.options="--tags @prebuild" -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Regression" -e
```

The `prebuild` tag is not running but `regression` is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax to pass multiple tags in Cucumber Serenity :**

mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @sanity --tags @regression"

Comment: this one didnt work for me. Both tags worlds when ran individually but not together. Does this suppose to work with specific cucumber version? I m using `cucumber 3.1.2`

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @sanity,@regression"
```

This means it is an AND operator and both the conditions needs to be satisfied